# Permission denied using Serial

Tags: python, serial, permissions

I'm using some XBee to build a mesh network and everything is working, **BUT**  only if I run the code using **sudo**. Now that the code is "Finished" i want to remove this need, because i know that it isn't good.

Basic serial reading code:

```py
import time
import serial
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os

os.system("sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyS0.service")
os.system("sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@serial0.service")

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.OUT)
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyS0',
    baudrate = 115200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1             
 )
while 1:
    x=ser.readline()    
    print(x)
```

Command sent to terminal:
**working:** `sudo python3 Desktop/Old/mustwork.py`
**doesn't work:** `python3 Desktop/Old/mustwork.py`
**error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 265, in open
    self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/serial0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/Old/mustwork.py", line 14, in <module>
    timeout=1             
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 13] could not open port /dev/serial0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/serial0'
```

Some raspberry configs:

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

$ cat /boot/config.txt
enable_uart=1

$ grep -v ^\# /boot/config.txt
enable_uart=1

$ ls -lh /dev/serial*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 mai 18 20:59 /dev/serial0 -> ttyS0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 mai 18 20:59 /dev/serial1 -> ttyAMA0

$ groups ${USER}
pi : pi adm tty dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev spi i2c gpio
```

Already went to raspi-config -5 -P6 -Enable

Comment: What are the rights on /dev/ttyS0?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you calling

```
os.system("sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyS0.service")
os.system("sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@serial0.service")
```

These are the same interface, and if you aren't using serial console it is better to disable (using `raspi-config`) then there is no need for sudo.

There is no need to use `sudo` with `/dev/serial0` provided the user is a member of group `dialout` (which is default for `pi`)

Incidentally why do you have serial in `/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages` this is included in the normal python library?

Comment: I'm using this os.system("sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@serial0.service") because sometimes i get an error message of a kind of conflict, like if the system was trying to access it too.
I know, it souldn't need sudo permission... =/

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer following [this](https://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3/) tutorial.

It worked after removing the line: 'console=serial0,115200', in the cmdline.txt like bellow:

```
$ sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt

dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes root wait
```

Comment: Rather than fiddling with the cmdline it is better to disable serial console in raspi-config, as suggested